# How to change the order of ancestors of flex child elements

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I'm working on a product page(https://codepen.io/oleksiukmary/pen/qPLPMb?editors=1100) and have 2 containers - content and image inside flex container. For mobile devices(<768px) I need to change the order of the image block (done):

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  padding: 5%;
  order: 2;
}
```

and move title and price from content block above image -> ex.

- title
- price
- image
- rest of the content

Title and price are ancestors of flex child, and from what I know I cant move them out of their container. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: As you discovered, it won't be possible to move them out of their container. Are you able to use a bit of JavaScript?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody yes, of course. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using a minimal amount of pure JavaScript (no jQuery). The idea is to clone the `.product__image` element and place the clone in the desired location (between `.product__price` and `.product__description`).

We'll then use some simple CSS to hide/show the clone/original at the different screen sizes. For screens below 768px we'll hide the original and show the clone, and for screens above 768px we'll show the original and hide the clone.

I've included a link to a Codepen at the bottom, which is easier to see the responsiveness.

```js
var productImage = document.querySelector('.product__image');
var productContent = document.querySelector('.product__content');
var productDescription = document.querySelector('.product__description');

productImageClone = productImage.cloneNode(true);
productContent.insertBefore(productImageClone, productDescription);
```

```css
.product {
  display: flex;
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  &__content {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 5% 10% 5%;
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      padding: 5%;
      order: 2;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 35px 28px 28px 28px;
    }
    .product__image {
      @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
        display: none;
      }
      @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        display: block;
      }
    }
  }
  &__title {
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    font-size: 38px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #000;
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      font-size: 28px;
      line-height: 30px;
    }
  }
  &__description {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #000;
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 18px;
    }
  }
  &__price {
    padding-bottom: 9px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 21px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #000;
    &--discount {
      color: #000;
      text-decoration: line-through;
    }
  }
  &__small-title {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
  }
  &__colors {
    padding: 10px 0;
    &-item {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: 14px;
    }
    &-link {
      width: 34px;
      height: 34px;
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      border-radius: 34px;
      text-align: center;
      img {
        width: 100%;
      }
      &:hover,
      &--active {
        border: 1px solid #000;
      }
    }
  }
  &__size {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    &-item {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: 12px;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 15px;
      font-weight: 700;
      color: #000;
    }
    &-link {
      width: 34px;
      height: 34px;
      display: inline-block;
      line-height: 34px;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      border-radius: 34px;
      &:hover,
      &--active {
        border: 1px solid #000;
      }
    }
  }
  .button {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  &__image {
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  &-thumbnails {
    &__item {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-top: 14px;
      margin-right: 23px;
      position: relative;
    }
    &__image {
      width: 117px;
      height: 117px;
    }
    &__link {
      &::after {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
        background-color: #fff;
        transition: opacity .5s ease;
      }
      &:hover {
        &::after {
          opacity: 0.5;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="product">
  <div class="product__content">
    <h1 class="product__title">Product name with short description</h1>
    <p class="product__price"><span class="product__price--discount">$24.99 </span>$19.99</p>
    <p class="product__description">Nam porttitor blandit accumsan. Ut vel dictum sem, a pretium dui. In malesuada enim in dolor euismod, id commodo mi consectetur. Curabitur at vestibulum nisi. Nullam vehicula nisi velit. Mauris turpis nisl, molestie ut</p>

    <p class="product__small-title">Color: white, red & gray</p>
    <ul class="product__colors">
      <li class="product__colors-item">
        <a href="#" class="product__colors-link"><img src="{{'black-red_color.svg' | asset_url }}" alt="Red white option"></a>
      </li>
      <li class="product__colors-item">
        <a href="#" class="product__colors-link"><img src="{{'black-red_color.svg' | asset_url }}" alt="Red white option"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <p class="product__small-title">Size: Small</p>
    <ul class="product__size">
      <li class="product__size-item"><a class="product__size-link" href="#">XS</a></li>
      <li class="product__size-item"><a class="product__size-link" href="#">S</a></li>
      <li class="product__size-item"><a class="product__size-link" href="#">M</a></li>
      <li class="product__size-item"><a class="product__size-link" href="#">L</a></li>
      <li class="product__size-item"><a class="product__size-link" href="#">XL</a></li>
    </ul>

    <a class="button button--green" href="#">Add your map</a>
    <a class="button" href="#">Add to Cart</a>


  </div>
  <div class="product__image">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2420/2709/t/1/assets/bg_girl_home-image.jpg?14680714382635068032" alt="Product">

    <ul class="product-thumbnails">
      <li class="product-thumbnails__item">
        <a class="product-thumbnails__link" href="#"><img class="product-thumbnails__image" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2420/2709/t/1/assets/product_image.jpg?14680714382635068032" alt="Product"></a>
      </li>
      <li class="product-thumbnails__item">
        <a class="product-thumbnails__link" href="#"><img class="product-thumbnails__image" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2420/2709/t/1/assets/product_image.jpg?14680714382635068032" alt="Product"></a>
      </li>
      <li class="product-thumbnails__item">
        <a class="product-thumbnails__link" href="#"><img class="product-thumbnails__image" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2420/2709/t/1/assets/product_image.jpg?14680714382635068032" alt="Product"></a>
      </li>
      <li class="product-thumbnails__item">
        <a class="product-thumbnails__link" href="#"><img class="product-thumbnails__image" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2420/2709/t/1/assets/product_image.jpg?14680714382635068032" alt="Product"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

And here's the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/brettdewoody/pen/qPLVqm?editors=1100) so you can experiment with the responsiveness.